# Java Http Client get 408 Request Time-out

Tags: java, http, request, client

I am developing a simple http client, but i have problem here:

*When using **telnet** on Windows command line*:

```
telnet download.microsoft.com 80


HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: download.microsoft.com
```

Response: 301 Moved Permanently

```
HEAD /download/7/A/9/7A9EBB22-8DC8-40A2-802D-B4CC343A928E/proplussp2013-kb2817430-fullfile-x86-vi-vn.exe HTTP/1.1
Host: download.microsoft.com
```

Response: 200 OK

*When using my program* (Eclipse IDE, JRE8)
This is my Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {
    public static DataInputStream in;
    public static BufferedWriter out;
    public static String host = "download.microsoft.com";
    public static int port = 80;
    public static Socket soc;

    public static String getHeader(String uri) throws IOException{

        String httpRequest = "HEAD " + uri + "\r\n"
                + "HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                + "Host:" + host
                + "\r\n";
        String httpResponse = "";
        int read;

        out.write(httpRequest);
        out.flush();

        while ((read = in.read()) != -1)
            httpResponse += (char)read;

        return httpResponse;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        soc = new Socket(host, port);
        in = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        out= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream())); 

        System.out.println(getHeader("/"));

        soc.close();
    }
}
```

With `getHeader("/")` it run about 20s then response HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out

With `getHeader("/download/7/A/9/7A9EBB22-8DC8-40A2-802D-B4CC343A928E/proplussp2013-kb2817430-fullfile-x86-vi-vn.exe")` it also get HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out

My code work Ok with another host. I also know that host download.microsoft.com is not normal accessible, but why with 2 method above it give different result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dump that contents of httpRequest to the screen and you'll see that you're building a broken request (CRLF instead of SP before http-version).

Furhtermore you're missing an additional CRLF (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#http.message)

Comment: change to:"HEAD " + uri + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" but still get 408 Request Time-out